# Why do I have to convert inputstream to string for using org.json.JSONArray package

Tags: java, json

I have an API which pushes me JSON array which has at least 1000 JSON object. I am reading that array from the API and writing it's content into the Redis server. My code is the following;

app.java

```
public class App {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {


        RedisOperations redis = new RedisOperations();
        redis.connect();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        URLConnection url = new URLConnection("url");
        HttpURLConnection conn = url.connect();
        String responseBody = convertStreamToString(conn.getInputStream());
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("That took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
        redis.addHashSet(jsonArray);        
}

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

RedisOperations.java

```
public class RedisOperations {

    Jedis jedis;
    Map<String, String> userProperties;

    public void connect() {

        try {

            jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
            System.out.println("Connection to server sucessfully");
            // check whether server is running or not
            System.out.println("Server is running: " + jedis.ping());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Can not connect to redis");
        }
    }

    public void addHashSet(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {

        userProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String no = "";

        for (int y = 0; y < jsonArray.length(); y++) {

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(y);
                no = jsonArray.getJSONObject(y).getString("NO");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.names().length(); i++) {

                    String key = jsonObject.names().getString(i);
                    String value = jsonObject.getString(jsonObject.names().getString(i));

                    userProperties.put(key, value);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Json object problem!");
            }

            try {

                jedis.hmset("user:" + no, userProperties);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot made redis operation");
            }
        }

    }

    public void deleteHashSet(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {

        for (int y = 0; y < jsonArray.length(); y++) {
            String no = jsonArray.getJSONObject(y).getString("NO");
            String keys = "user:" + no;
            System.out.println(keys);
            jedis.del(keys);
        }

    }
}
```

After my research I found that I can read data from URL as inputstream. To use org.json.JSONArray package and it's methods I have to convert that inputstream to string and it's time consuming. Total execution time is 3300ms and converting inputstream to string takes 2700ms. It's huge time!

My problem is I am already taking data as JSON array. Is there a way that I can use that package and methods without converting inputstream to string?

Thanks for you suggestions!

Comment: JSON _IS_ a string, and not a byte array. So somewhere between the byte stream of the connection and the parsing JSON handler it has to be converted to a string, otherwise a JSON parser cannot read it.